# Setting a graphic to the bottom center of the phone

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Hello can any one help me, I am trying to get a graphic to be at the bottom of the screen and centered using LinearLayout. I would rather use the Bitmap method, because this is for a game. Thanks

Comment: Is this for Android development purposes?  If so, you should tag your post for Android...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by bitmap method but this will do what you ask:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```